# Mysql where condition on columns

Tags: mysql

Minimal example

```
select a.order_id as X from orders as a
WHERE
X > 8000
```

query will fail as X is not a column, any solution?

other example

```
select (if (E.size > 0, E.Size, (B.height x B.width)) as sizeX from
orders as a, report as E, size as B

where

(E.id = a.id and B.id = a.id)
and
sizeX > 100
```

my query may contain typos, but I hope my question is clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1) Use `HAVING` (not very efficient since the conditions from having clause are applied AFTER the results are returned and thus NO indexes are used)

```
select a.order_id as X from orders as a
HAVING
X > 8000
```

2) Use the column name (efficient if you have a index an the column used in where clause)

```
select a.order_id as X from orders as a
WHERE
a.order_id > 8000
```

Comment: +1 Third option: turn the query into a sub-query; use a where clause on the column alias outside the sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause see the doc [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)